# Fontawesome icons React

Tags: reactjs, windows, icons

How can i add an icon like this (i added from a tutorial from this forum):

[fonteawesome facebook icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGHuh.png)

in React? Because i added this like this:

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faFacebookF } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons' 


<FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fab', 'facebook-f']} className="fb-icon-style" />


library.add(faFacebookF);
```

---- And that's it! But now how can i add icons like this: https://fontawesome.com/icons/globe or this https://fontawesome.com/icons/youtube ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work

### Solution

```
import { faFacebookF, faYoutube } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
import { faGlobe } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'; 


<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faYoutube} />
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebookF} />
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faGlobe} />
```

> Note: Install `@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons` if not installed already

Comment: Pleasure! If helped then please accept and upvote the answer to help us. :)

Answer (score 0):

You do it like this:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faFacebookF } from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons"


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebookF} />

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Make sure you import relevant npm packages:

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
```